# Editable data grid view throwing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am trying to create an editable DataGridView and I have enabled the "`AutoGenerateEditButton`" to true but when i click the edit on the page it throws this excetion

> "System.Web.HttpException: The GridView 'GridView1' fired event
>   RowEditing which wasn't handled."

Any ideas why? 
The code that I am using is below

I would also like to know how i would be able to update the edited value into the datatable so its updated.

### Html

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" Width="1060px">
</asp:GridView>
```

### C# (Code Behind)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        add();
    }
}

private void add()
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Columns.Add("ab", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("ac", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("av", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("ax", typeof(string));
     DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
     row["ac"] = "sndasbfb";
     row["av"] = "sndasbfb";
     row["av"] = "sndasbfb";
     row["ax"] = "sndasbfb";
     dt.Rows.Add(row);
     GridView1.DataSource = dt;
     GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a onrowediting event..

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
                    Width="1060px" Onrowediting="Gridview_rowediting">

                </asp:GridView>


protected void Gridview_rowediting(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

}
```

TO update the gridview add onrowupdating event..

```
protected void Gridview_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   update();

}
private void update()
{
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("ab", typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("ac", typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("av", typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("ax", typeof(string));
 DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
 row["ac"] = "newvalue";
 row["av"] = "newvalue";
 row["av"] = "newvalue";
 row["ax"] = "newvalue";
 dt.Rows.Add(row);
 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
 GridView1.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: Once i have added this is there any other code to add to the method,

Comment: will this upadte the dt table

Comment: it compes up with the edit but when i click update it throws another excetion

Comment: i have used the op update method but its not updateing the datatable any ideas how i can do this

Comment: what are u trying to do exactly? and what was that exception u got while uploading..

Comment: I am trying to edit the row and when edited i would lie to update them changes to the datatable

Comment: can u give me an example becuase i dont understand

Comment: soory i menats what if i only wanted to edit one coloun in the row

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Event for the RowEditing

Look here for further information:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1144799/1850877.aspx#1850877

---

```
gvSalesEventSearch.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(gvSalesEventSearch_RowEditing);

void gvSalesEventSearch_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggesting you have not handled the `OnRowEditing="GridViewEditEventHandler"` event.
Which get triggered if the default `edit link` is click on the `gridview`

You will need to handle `OnRowEditing` as follows

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
         AutoGenerateEditButton="True" Width="1060px">
</asp:GridView>
```

and In the code behind you will have to handle this event as follow

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  //  GridView1.SelectedIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
      //do your stuff here
    add();
}
```